# Make Line Numbers Appear in Documentation

Tags: neovim, formatting, help-system, line-numbers, init.vim

I have `set number` in my init.vim (I am using neovim) and it works fine for any buffers I'm editing.  However, I have to enter `:set number` into the command line to make line numbers appear in the documentation.  This goes for other display settings I have as well (such as wrapping links in the documentation with vertical bars: can't set it in my init.vim, have to manually set it once I enter the documentation.  How to I make settings from my init.vim apply to the documentation?

Notably the colorscheme I set in my init.vim file does apply to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `number` and/or `relativenumber` for the help docs like so:

```
augroup vim help
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType help setlocal number
    autocmd FileType help setlocal relativenumber
augroup END
```

Comment: You missed augroup END, and idk if the name can be more than one word. Also consider ftplugins for this

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble. I know that you can use more than one word for the group name. I didn't know about ftplugins - I'll look them up, cheers!